# Uanble to connect to remote mysql

Tags: mysql, django, remote-access, remote-server

I'm trying to connect to remote MySQL through my Django application.

```
'client4': {
                'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
                'NAME': config('DATABASE_NAME_5'),
                'USER': 'username',
                'PASSWORD': config('DATABASE_PASSWORD_PHPMYADMIN'),
                'HOST': 'xxx.xx.xxx.xxx',
                'PORT': '3306',
            },
```

When I run makemigrations,

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'username'@'yyy.yy.yyy.yyy' (using password: YES)")
```

This error pops. But the IP address shown here is different and unknown to me. I tried connecting to 2 different IP addresses but the same IP address keeps popping in the error.

I tried to connect to a remote server using the terminal command,

```
mysql -u root -h xxx.xxx.xx.xxx -p
```

Led to the same error,

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'yyy.yy.yyy.yyy' (using password: YES)
```

with the same IP popping up again.
I am unable to figure out what where this IP is coming from.
I also checked my local IPs using

```
ifconfig
```

But this IP was not seen anywhere.
Please help me out here.
Thanks.

**UPDATE**
The IP appearing in the error is my computer's wan IP

Comment: You might be using some proxy or firewall (either on your machine or the database might be behind it), etc. and that IP might be the proxies IP.

Comment: How can I check it?

Comment: What is the value for 'default'?

Comment: @MohamedElKalioby it is empty.

Comment: You're actually trying to connect to MySQL (or MariaDB); phpMyAdmin is a web-based administrative interface that connects to the database server and does not offer an API for you to access from Python.

Comment: Yeah right. But it is saying Access denied as I mentioned with the computer's WAN IP. What settings or configurations do I need to change? @IsaacBennetch

Answer (score 0):

I think because you are setting `client4` not `default`.

Comment: I have kept it empty. I am using multiple databases with routers.